# How do I extend the EmberJS handlebars input helpers to support attributes without values?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently using the Ember input helpers to render data bound form controls:

`{{input class="form-control" type="email" value=email }}`

This generates the following HTML:

`<input id="ember502" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control" type="email" value="person@example.com">`

HTML 5 input controls support the **required** attribute on elements.  This attribute has no value.  Attempting to pass the value into the template causes a compilation error and using something like `required=true` will not function correctly since the attribute is not empty.

How can I modify the ember TextInput view to include attributes without values?  I've attempted to subclass it but the API is preventing direct access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default ember doesn't map all options passed to input view helper like html attributes. You can achieve this using `attributeBindings`.

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['required']
});
```

Give a look in that fiddle to see this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/hRx5E/

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution I overlooked!  This resolved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case using only `attributeBindings` did not help. I wanted to add an empty **download** HTML attribute to an `a` tag, but it was skipped. What I had to do was that I needed to set also the download property to an empty string.

In such a case try to use instead of this:

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['required']
});
```

this snippet:

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['required']
    required: ''
});
```

Maybe it will help ;-)